# Change mysql data directory to a network location in windows

Tags: mysql, windows, networking

I need to change the datadir of mysql on windows to a net location \192.168.1.101\something
I try this solution:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/change-existing-datadir-path-in-mysql

I create the file my.ini

```
[mysqld]
datadir=\\192.168.1.101\something
```

but this is not working;

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysql -hlocalhost -u root -p
Enter password: ********
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.12 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql> show variables like 'datadir';
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                                                             |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| datadir       | C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

how can i change my data directory to a network location in windows?

Comment: Storing your MySQL data on a network drive is probably a super bad idea. I'm not sure if that's even supported, as the low-level IO calls might be wildly out of order without direct access to the device. In any case, MySQL needs a drive letter and path, not a network path.

Comment: my database is actually in a centos machine, I share the folder with SAMBA, is there another way to make Windows to access the database from CentOS

Comment: The database process and the associated files should be on the same physical machine. If you want to access MySQL remotely, why don't you just connect with your client to the right machine? I'm not sure what your goal is here.

Comment: We can specify data directory as an external/removable drive . but for a network location no idea!